# App Engine serving old version intermittently

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've deployed a new version which contains just one image replacement. After migrating traffic (100%) to the new version I can see that only this version now has active instances. However 2 days later and App engine is still intermittently serving the old image. So I assume the previous version. When I ping the domain I can see that the latest version has one IP address and the old version has another.

My question is how do I force App Engine to only server the new version? I'm not using traffic splitting either.

Any help would be much appreciated

Regards,
Danny

Comment: It sounds like a caching issue. Did the old image and the new image have the same name?

Comment: Hi Kekito, yes they do have the same name. But if have also flushed the men cache and luck. Is there some other cache settings I should be a ware of? Thanks!

Comment: If it has fixed itself by now, then it was a caching issue. If not, then it is something else.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache

Comment: Thanks for your help! After approx 4 days the new image is appearing consistently so was definitely a caching issue... I need to looks into techniques to speed this up though as Tim suggests below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple layers of caches beyond memcache,

Googles edge cache will definitely cache static content especially if you app is referenced by your domain and not appspot.com .

You will probably need to use some cache busting techniques.

You can test this by requesting the url that is presenting old content with the same url but appending something like ?x=1 to the url.

If you then get current content then the edge cache is your problem and therefore the need to use cache busting techniques.